# Troubleshooting/mitigating a token leak in unsupported black box software

Tags: windows-xp, token

Let's say there is a program on my Windows XP system leaking.exe which leaks token handles at a rate that will eventually render the system unusable. It's black box to me, can't get support or examine/debug/modify the source code.

Also let's say restarting the system and restarting leaking.exe are undesirable fixes. This will work but I am trying to find a way to avoid it.

All I know at this point is using process explorer I can see it is building a massive list of token handles, for the default login user.

I don't know much about token resources. What would be a typical cause for a token leak? Seems to me something like starting a thread that never ends, but there is no thread leaking going on.

How would token handles relate to other resources like files or other running processes? If there were a way to mitigate this problem by manipulating something else related to the leak that would be nice.

Sorry for the vague details but it is a very vague problem. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: This sounds more like a programming question to me.